# Is there a way to use the TimeSeries Insights graphs in your website?

Tags: azure, timeserieschart

I'm in love with the Azure TimeSeries Insights portal and what to use the graph component on my Angular website.

Does anyone know if they are planning to make them usable as a component?

Answer (score 0):

Found a github project doing this: 
https://tsiclientsample.azurewebsites.net/